# The program is not running in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am Trying to make phone book in c++ using unordered map.There is no error in the code its executing perfectly in cpp.sh but not in visual studio 2017 can any one help me with it? Am I missing any library or any statement or should I try Any thing else.
Here is my code:

```
  #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
 using namespace std;
 int a;
    class phoneBook {
 public:
int y;
string name;
long int number;
unordered_map <string, long int>::iterator it;
unordered_map<string, long int> m;
void enter()
{

    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter Phone Number: ";
    cin >> number;
    m.insert(make_pair(name, number));
    return;
}
void search()
{
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);
    it = m.find(name);
    if (it != m.end())
    {
        cout << "Name:- " << name << endl;
        cout << "Number:- " << it->second << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Not Found";
       }
       cout << endl;
        return;
       }
      };
     int main()
    {
        phoneBook p;
       while (a != 0)
      {
            cout << "Enter 1 to add phone number" << endl;
              cout << "Enter 2 to search for phone number" << endl;
          cout << "Enter 0 to exit" << endl;
            cin >> a;
    if (a == 1)
    {
        p.enter();
    }
    if (a == 0 || a == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (a == 2)
    {
        p.search();
    }
}
return 0;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? You need to be more specific for us to be able to help you. The first thing I would do is remove `system("pause");`

Comment: Without system("pause") black screen is not appearing and if I include system("pause") the black screen appears but not executing the program.

Comment: It worked on my system, but I don't have Visual Studio.  Must be something with how you are using Visual Studio.

Comment: It also works in cpp.sh but its not working in visual studio 2017 nor visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is global variable, its default value is 0, hence when main function starts condition in your while loop `a != 0` returns false and `main` ends working.

Initialize `a` variable with value other than 0.

Comment: so what should I do? please help me. I first declare "a" inside the main but it was giving a error.

Comment: move definition of `a` variable into main function, and set its value to 1. `int main () { int a =1 ; ... }`